# How to print out the inverted index created by elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

If I wanted to get all the tokens of the index that elasticsearch creates (I'm using the [rails elasticsearch gem](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)), how would I go about doing that?  Doing something like this only gets a particular set of tokens for a search term:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/development_test/_analyze?text=John Smith'
```

Comment: There is no api provided by elasticsearch to view the lucene index. 
However there are some tools like Luke which allow you to view lucene index. 
Here is a [blog][1] about how to set it up for elasticsearch probably might help. 



  [1]: http://rosssimpson.com/blog/2014/05/06/using-luke-with-elasticsearch/

Comment: Thanks I managed to get Luke up and running..any idea where the indices elasticsearch creates are stored on Linux?  I checked /etc/init.d and didn't see any .idx file.

Comment: index path should be provided in the  path.data field in the config  of elasticsearch. the indices should be in a path similar to    <path.data> /<cluster_name>/<nodes>/<indices>/<node_id>/indices/

Comment: How do I find the path.data? I tried curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings' and received {"settings":{"index":{"uuid":"XXXX","number_of_replicas":"1","number_of_shards":"2","version":{"created":"1020199"}}}}

Comment: assuming es server is localhost:9200  curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/fs?pretty" should show you the path field.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/search-request-scroll.html) with the [Term Vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/docs-termvectors.html) to enumerate terms in the inverted index:

```rb
require "elastomer/client"
require "set"

client = Elastomer::Client.new({ :url => "http://localhost:9200" })
index = "someindex"
type = "sometype"
field = "somefield"

terms = Set.new

client.scan(nil, :index => index, :type => type).each_document do |document|
  term_vectors = client.index(index).docs(type).termvector({ :fields => field, :id => document["_id"] })["term_vectors"]
  if term_vectors.key?(field)
    term_vectors[field]["terms"].keys.each do |term|
      unless terms.include?(term)
        terms << term
        puts(term)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is rather slow and wasteful since it performs a `_termvectors` HTTP request for every single document in the index, holds all the terms in RAM, and keeps a scroll context open for the duration of enumeration. However, this doesn't require another tool like Luke and the terms can be streamed out of the index.